# how to avoid color overlap for matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple data in one plot with matplotlib. Part of the data will overlap with each other. When I plot the graph, the overlapped areas produce different colors as shown in this graph
[image]

Is there a way to prevent the overlapped area to produce extra color in matplotlib. The graph I want to plot is like this graph
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post a complete example, you don't seem to be using matplotlib default colors. Setting `alpha=1.0` in each of your `plot` calls should be enough to fix it.

Comment: Hi, I used alpha settings to tune the color in the first graph. My question is how to avoid color mixture in the overlapped area even I set the alpha value less than 1.

Comment: Hi, filippo, thank you for your reply. The way I defined the color is similar to this example. https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-scatter-py How can I make sure the color for the overlapped area is the not combination of two colors or more than two colors. @filippo

Comment: You just set alpha to 1, if you don't like default colors (too dark?) you can define your own. See e.g. https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's helpful.